# How to filter data from a public CSV in the web with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm pulling data from a public csv to a Google Spreadsheets.
The amount of data is really big and Gsheets can't proccess that amount of information. That's why I want to filter this results to get only the ones that custom_label2 = 7394141.

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
function importCSVFromWeb() {

  // Provide the full URL of the CSV file.
  var csvUrl = "https://storage.googleapis.com/bi_enjoei/export_google/feed_enjoei.csv";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated my response with a BigQuery alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can filter the data, you may need to fetch it all.

Unfortunately, [there is a limit on how much data you can download using UrlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) (max of 100MB per day, your CSV is 447MB and counting).

Its simply not possible to process a CSV of that size using pure Apps Script.

However, if the server where the CSV resides supports [partial requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) you might be able to fetch just the data you need.

This will depend heavily on how the CSV is structured; if the CSV stores a fixed number of bytes per row of data and that label value (custom_label2) is always sequential then this approach is viable since you'll be able to calculate the byte offset needed to seek to the correct row of data.

But if the data is sparse, where each row is stored so that it only takes up only as much space as needed then row sizes can vary, or if the label value is arbitrary, then this method won't work.

---

Another alternative is to leverage [Big Query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/).

Since your CSV lives in google cloud storage (and assuming you own that cloud storage container) you can [point to it as an external data source in Big Query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources).

Once you have that setup you can run a SQL-like query using Google Apps Script via [the Big Query Advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery) to fetch the row(s) where custom_label2 = 7394141.

Then you can proceed to add that row data to a spreadsheet.